# How replace variable of the bash from cadshell

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

and i don't understand how to change or how to set variable of the bash from cadshell.

This is my bash:

```
setenv LINUX_HOST something
alias cometa '\xhost +{$LINUX_HOST} ; ssh $LINUX_HOST -l \* xterm -display
```

when i run my tool cometa, in this version i wrote:

```
cometa my_user_name
```

after it was connect to LINUX_HOST something

How can I create something like this

```
cometa my_user_name HOST
```

after my_user_name I enter HOST name, and the new HOST name will replace something

Comment: That looks like csh syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Change the alias into a function:

```bsh
unalias cometa
cometa() {
    local username=$1
    local host=${2:-$LINUX_HOST}
    command xhost +{"$host"}
    ssh -l "$username" "$host" xterm -display
}
```

The `${2:-$LINUX_HOST}` syntax uses the value of $LINUX_HOST if the 2nd argument is empty or unset.